# Static final member variables vs. get methods

Tags: java, static, final

I have a class with all the configuration from a property file.

My first solution is this:

```
public class Config {

    public static final int disc;

    static {

        // Read property file and set properties

        disc = 5;
    }
}
```

Reading the information in this way:

```
System.out.println(Config.disc);
```

The second solution is:

```
public class Config {

    private int disc;

    public void Config() {

        // Read property file and set properties

        disc = 5;
    }

    public int getDisc() {
        return this.disc;
    }
}
```

Reading in that way:

```
System.out.println(new Config().getDisc());
```

What's the best way and why? What the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Your first solution doesn't compile.

Comment: It rather looks like your trying to make a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (in which case a Singleton would be the best way).

Comment: Please, recheck your code before posting it next time.

Comment: It was a static block not a constructor. I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the meaning of `disc`:

- If `disc` represents a constant, essentially giving a name to a numeric value, than a public final field is better
- If `disc` represents a value that could change as the result of user's actions (i.e. if it is part of configuration) then a private variable with a getter is preferable.

The second approach gives you more flexibility, should you decide to refactor your class in the future: it lets you initialize the private `disc` at a later time, or replace it with some other way of obtaining a value, e.g. by computing it from other values, or reading from another object.

Answer (score 1):

using `getDisc()` you can have one disc variable per object while `static disc` is shared across all the instances.

- If you have different `disc` value for every instance of class, then
  go for second approach.
- If you have same value which needs to be shared across all the instances of the class, then use the first approach

By they way, you cannot do `System.out.println(Config.getDisc());`. You can't call a non-static method using class name

Answer (score 1):

What about: `public static final int DISC = 5;`
Then you can use `Config.DISC` to access your config value.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Config.getDisc());
```

This is wrong. You can't call a non-static method with class name. You must create an object as following:

```
Config cfg = new Config();
System.out.println(cfg.getDisc());
```

Now, In your first case all the instances will share same copy of `disc`. so, if it's not a constant, go for 2nd case.

Answer (score 0):

What you want in this case is really

```
public static final int DISC = 5;

System.out.println(Config.DISC);
```

(Note that members like these are conventionally always written in capticals).

---

Your **first solution** has an error in it. It won't compile because you try to set a final field multiple times. Each time you create a `new Config()`, you will assign a value to `disc`, but since it is final that won't work. What you probably wanted to suggest was to put it in the static constructor:

```
public class Config
{
    public static final int DISC;
    static
    {
        DISC = 5;
    }
}
```

However, I do not recommend it, because is is totaly find to do it the first way I wrote and is much easier as well.

Your **second solution** has an error in it. It won't compile because you can't access the non-static method from a static context. This means that you first will have to create an instance of Config, before you can call the `getDisc()` method. The better solution in this case is to declare the method as static.